# Returning array from JQuery For Each Loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to return an array of some simple information from a for each loop without success. Here is the code I'm using in two different functions.

```
function getUser(uname, callback) {
var u = "http://itsuite.it.brighton.ac.uk/john10/ci227/a1/whois.php?username=" + uname;
return $.get(uname, {}, callback);
}

function parseUserInfo(usrname) {
getUser(usrname, function(data) {
    var x = new Array();
    $(this).find("user").each(function() {
        x['username'] = $(this).find("username").text();
        x['firstname'] = $(this).find("firstname").text();
        x['surname'] = $(this).find("surname").text();
        return x;
    }
}
}
```

All I'm getting when I use it like this:

```
var dat = parseUserInfo("guest");
```

Is Undefined when using the console.log(dat) so could someone tell me where I'm going wrong here?

Many Thanks! Oh Btw I have looked at other solutions on here and elsewhere but as yet cannot find anything that works for me, so please no 'this thread is a duplicate' or 'its been answered here' links coz that will put me back to square one and make asking this question pointless!

Answer (score 2):

`x` is getting returned to the `getUser()` function. You need to define and return `x` outside the `getUser()` in `parseUserInfo()`.

So your code should look something like this:

```
function parseUserInfo(usrname) {
  var x = new Array();
  getUser(usrname, function(data) {
    $(this).find("user").each(function() {
      x['username'] = $(this).find("username").text();
      x['firstname'] = $(this).find("firstname").text();
      x['surname'] = $(this).find("surname").text();
    });
  });
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Correct, if you use `return false` instead of `return x` it would just break `$.each` loop.

Comment: Yes but how do I do that? This is what my question was about.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, in your answer none of the functions are closed off properly with the ); at the end and in each point I tried putting the return x; after it, I just got returned with parseUserInfo is undefined, could you please modify the code to how it should look? - Further to this, I closed the getUser and .each functions off myself and still got same result, aside from one but returned an empty array. Console logged: []

Comment: I've solved the syntax errors by closing the functions. Try putting a `console.log(data);` between the 3rd and 4th line of my code. Lets see what, if any data you're getting from the `$.get()` request.

Comment: Undefined and [] on separate lines are all the console is giving, this is a nightmare, I don't understand how it is so hard to return an array of the data.

Comment: You're probably not using the `$.get()` on the correct URL if you're not getting any output from `console.log(data)`. You might want to recheck what the URL returns via some other tool or with your browser. The URL seems blocked for me, so no way for me to check it.

Comment: The getUser() does return something from the $.get() function and I forgot to mention that when I popped a console.log(data) in the right place I did get a #document which when expanded had the data in it. So that function is certainly working, it just does not seem to be able to return anything from the $.each() loop. The data that is returned is in XML format by the way, probably should of mentioned this.